# Convert from List into IEnumerable format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, ienumerable

```
IEnumerable<Book> _Book_IE
List<Book> _Book_List
```

How shall I do in order to convert `_Book_List` into `IEnumerable` format?

Comment: At least he has a convention, eh?

Comment: For people wondering why Kirk's comment have so many "ups", it's because you can't just name your variable the way you want ! there are conventions for that, and it is highly recommended that you follow them, so that your code can be clear and understandable, this will help the people trying to help you in places like Stack-overflow or GitHub! for further information read the book : **Clean Code** by Robert C. Martin.

Comment: ...and how to go about a naming convention without falling prey to the Smurf Naming anti-pattern?  https://devcards.io/smurf-naming-convention
Typically a namespace can provide specificity where needed.

Comment: Convertint to ienumerable is specially useful when you need to use the .Reverse() in a Linq expression

Answer (score 193, accepted):

You don't need to convert it. [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) implements the [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) interface so it is already an enumerable.

This means that it is perfectly fine to have the following:

```
public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks()
{
    List<Book> books = FetchEmFromSomewhere();    
    return books;
}
```

as well as:

```
public void ProcessBooks(IEnumerable<Book> books)
{
    // do something with those books
}
```

which could be invoked:

```
List<Book> books = FetchEmFromSomewhere();    
ProcessBooks(books);
```

Comment: If you function returns a Task<IEnumerable<Book>> and you try to return Task.FromResult(list_of_books) this will not work. I used the AsEnumerable extension method to come around this.

Answer (score 116):

You can use the extension method AsEnumerable in Assembly System.Core and System.Linq namespace :

```
List<Book> list = new List<Book>();
return list.AsEnumerable();
```

This will, as said on [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx) change the type of the List in compile-time.
This will give you the benefits also to only enumerate your collection we needed (see MSDN example for this).

Comment: If you are not suppose to add something to the Collection then you should use/return IEnumerable.

Comment: using System.Linq;

Answer (score 18):

Why not use a Single liner ...

```
IEnumerable<Book> _Book_IE= _Book_List as IEnumerable<Book>;
```

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. It means that you do not have to convert or cast anything.

Comment: It depends. If you try to set a `IEnumerable<IList<obj>>` to an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<obj>>` it gives a compiler error since the second does not inherit from the first one.

Answer (score 6):

```
IEnumerable<Book> _Book_IE;
List<Book> _Book_List;
```

If it's the generic variant:

```
_Book_IE = _Book_List;
```

If you want to convert to the non-generic one:

```
IEnumerable ie = (IEnumerable)_Book_List;
```

Comment: You don't need the cast here.

Comment: You do if you want the specific methods from the non-generic interface, as some of them are explicitly implemented, or am I'm on the wrong track here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
using System.Linq;
```

to use `IEnumerable` options at your `List`.