# Save list to database entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
 internal static bool SaveUOSChangeLog(List<Contracts.DataContracts.UOSChangeLog> values, string user)
    {
        try
        {
            using(var ctx = new StradaDataReviewContext2())
            {
                values.ForEach(u => { u.Username = user; u.Changed = DateTime.Now; });
                var test = ctx.UOSChangeLog.Add(values);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
        }
```

The thing I want to do Is to save `values` to the database. However, I get a the following error message:

[image]

Here is my Contracts.DataContracts.UOSChangeLog:

```
   public int? Id { get; set; }
        public int Accident_nr { get; set; }
        public int Refnr { get; set; }
        public int Action { get; set; }
        public string Old_data { get; set; }
        public string New_data { get; set; }
        public DateTime SearchedFromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime SearchedToDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime Changed { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
```

And here Is my Services.StradaDataReview2Model.UOSChangeLog that are used as a `DbSet`

```
[Table("UOSChangeLog")]
    public partial class UOSChangeLog
    {
        [Required]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public int Accident_nr { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Refnr { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Action { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Old_data { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string New_data { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime SearchedFromDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime SearchedToDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime Changed { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: your are trying to add a new List of specified class (values is a List) rather than a specific instance

Comment: @apomene: Hm, okey, and how should I do It then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to add a list with the `Add` method which takes a single object, just keep it simple and use a foreach:

```
using(var ctx = new StradaDataReviewContext2())
{
   foreach(var value in values)
   {
       value.Username = user;
       value.Changed = DateTime.Now;
       ctx.UOSChangeLog.Add(value);
   }
   ctx.SaveChanges();
   return true;
}
```

Just use a simple foreach, linq is a querying language, not a modifying language.

Comment: @Bryan That's the best option, by using linq foreach you're not actually gaining anything

Comment: Hi again, I still get the same error when doing like you do.

Comment: @Bryan `value` is of type `UOSChangeLog` right? Can you copy the error message?

Comment: Here u can find a printscreen on the values of value list: http://postimg.org/image/56uxs9yzb/ and here you can find the error message: http://postimg.org/image/4felk4dir/

Comment: @Bryan They're of different types. Your values are from `Contracts.DataContracts` namespace, and your objectcontext is `Strada.DataReview...` namespace. You'll have to create the right object to add it (of the `Strada` namespace).

Comment: U mean that I must use the Model for my DbSet?

Comment: @Bryan Yes, create a new model of your DbSet and fill in the properties from the other object. You can't add an object of another type to the dbset

Comment: AlexanderDerck: Thank u :)

Answer (score 7):

Please use addrange method.

```
db.TheTable.AddRange(TheList)
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Entity Framework's .AddRange method to add a collection of objects to your Db.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange(v=vs.113).aspx)

It will look like:

```
       using(var ctx = new StradaDataReviewContext2())
        {
            values.ForEach(u => { u.Username = user; u.Changed = DateTime.Now; });
            var test = ctx.UOSChangeLog.AddRange(values);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: List<T> implements IEnumerable  MSDN - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx -- Stack Overflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700613/convert-from-list-into-ienumerable-format

Comment: Ah okey. But I Still get same error described In my question.

Comment: Stupid question: your context does inherit DbContext, correct?

Comment: @DanOrlovsky If I call List.Clear() after AddRange, will the db still have the data?

Comment: @Austin_Anderson - so long as you savechanges, you should be OK.